# Docker: vethXXXXXXX: Failed to get link config: No such device

Tags: docker, networking, containers, virtual-ethernet

My docker container fails to communicate with the outside world no matter ports are open and network is properly set. I get ping, container is started without issues, but does not communicate over tcp. I get the error
`systemd-udevd[11922]: veth09e2558: Failed to get link config: No such device`

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?